# C++ Input ints into vector via ranged for loop; random 0s

Tags: c++, vector, ranged-loops

I am using a ranged for loop to input random values into a vector. However, when i output the values of the vector there is a set of trailing zeros. I do not know where they came from.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int  double1(int number)
void double2 (int &number);
void double3 (int *number);

void triple1 (int array1[], int size);
void triple2 (array<int, 10> &array2);
void triple3 (vector<int>    *array3);

int main(){
    int array1[10];
    int copy_array1[10];
    array<int, 10> array2;
    array<int, 10> copy_array2;
    vector<int> array3(10);
    vector<int> copy_array3(10);
    for(int x = 0; x <10; x++){
        array1[x] = rand() % (101 -50) + 50;
    }
    for(auto &n : array2){
        n = rand() % (101 -50) + 50;
    }
    for(auto a : array3){
        array3.push_back(rand() % (101 -50) + 50);
    }
    copy(begin(array1), end(array1), begin(copy_array1));
    copy_array3 = array3;
    copy_array2 = array2;
    cout <<"Arrays loaded with random numbers from 50 - 100" << endl;
    cout << "=====================================================" << endl;
    cout <<"Array1: ";
    for(int x = 0; x<10; x++){
        cout << setw(5) << left << array1[x];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout <<"Array2: ";
    for(int x:array2){
        cout << setw(5) << left << x;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout <<"Array3: ";
    for(int x:array3){
       // if( x != 0)
            cout << setw(5) << left << x;
    }
    cout << endl;
    double1(array1);

}
```

The output gives me:

```
Arrays loaded with random numbers from 50 - 100
=====================================================
Array1: 91   55   60   81   94   66   53   83   84   85
Array2: 94   94   75   98   66   82   87   58   83   80
Array3: 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    56   68   76   50   87   90   80   100  82   55
```

I have to use a ranged for loop. I have been confused on what those extra zeros are doing there in array3. I set the size of the vector to ten, but using .size() reveals the size is actually 20. Why did the vector put ten zeros in front of my random values?

Comment: You initialized your vector with 10 zero elements 

Answer (score 4):

There are extra zeros because you put them there. I'm not kidding, you did it right here:

```
vector<int> array3(10);
```

The [`std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you used is the one that accepts how many elements the vector should be initialized with. So it allocates space, and then value initializes them, which for integers means zero initialize.

At this point, `array3` isn't an empty vector with space for 10 more integers. It's a vector with 10 integers (all 0) already present. So when you `push_back` some more, it's all added after those *existing* items.

If you want to overwrite them, like you do with `std::array`, then you can employ the exact same loop you did for `array2`. If on the other hand you *really* want to use `push_back`, then you need to construct an **empty** vector (you may call `reserve` on it, after construction), and `push_back` into it 10 times. A range-based for won't work in this case, because the vector is constructed empty. So the loop will be over an empty range, and so just won't do anything.

Comment: Ahh so the (10) reserves the memory AND sets them to zero? I have tried to array3.reserve(10) but then the vector comes out with an empty size and no values inputted??

Comment: @PaulPark - That constructor creates a non-empty vector. `reserve` only makes sure you have enough space, it doesn't add items. For `std::vector` there's a difference between *available* storage, and *occupied* storage. That's why two different member functions exist. `capacity` for how much space is available, and `size` for how much of it is used. So yet, a vector can hold on to space, but still be an empty range, because there are no items created inside it.

Comment: okok i think im starting to get it. So if I reserve 10 memory locations then I can push_back 10 values? Which means I won't be able to use a ranged for loop to input the values?

Comment: @PaulPark - Pretty much. If you resrve 10, you can push_back 10 without needing to allocate space for more. But `push_back` will expand the vector if you try to do it an eleventh time, so reserve is about saving in operations. And yes, merely reserving will still keep the vector in an *empty* state. So a range for over it won't do anything.

Comment: Sigh I was afraid of that. The requirement is to load the vector with random ints with a ranged for loop. Been trying to avoid a standard for-loop. Thanks for your help and explanations it really helped me out. I am gou2ng to do some more research on empty states in vectors.

Comment: @PaulPark - Well, you can do that with a range-based for loop. Just keep constructing those 10 integers, and don't `push_back`. Overwrite them, as you do with `std::array`.

Comment: ?Would i use something like assign or insert? I don't quite follow you

Comment: @PaulPark - No, you would do the exact same thing you do for `array2`. Iterate over the *elements* with a reference, and assign to each element.

Comment: @PaulPark - Yes

Comment: Huh `for(auto &a : array3){
        a = rand() % (101 -50) + 50;
    }`

Comment: @PaulPark - Yes. That'll do it, if you must use a range-based for loop. Coupled with your original initialization of the vector of course

Comment: This can not work because 'a' is only storing the address of array3 its not pointing at the adress, or am i mistaken?

Comment: It just returns a blank vector.

Comment: @PaulPark - Then why does `n` work for `array2`? It's not different if your range isn't empty. It's quite obvious you changed more than just the loop, but I'm not really up for a debug by comments session.

Comment: array2 was an array class while array3 was a vector. But yah its strange. I think im gonna have to do more research. Thanks for your help! :)